# Replace all instances of a character in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="example">Some example text</div>
<div class="example">Some more example text</div>
```

How can I remove all instances of the letter 'e' (case sensitivity not necessary) in the elements above without preexisting ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function() {
    this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace(/e/g, '');
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jKNWb/)​

If you want `e` or `E` use this:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    this.innerHTML= this.innerHTML.replace(/e|E/g, '');
});
```

If there are elements inside those `<div>`s use the `text` function to get only the textNodes:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text().replace(/e|E/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: @mamoo. True, but it's fine for his example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the content of the inner text (and not generically all the 'e's inside the tag):

```
$(yourselector).each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).text.replace(/e/g, ''));
});
```

PS
Corrected after gdoron remark...

Answer (score 0):

```
var de = document.documentElement;
de.innerHTML = de.innerHTML.replace(/>.*?</g, function(a, b) {
    return a.replace(/e/g, "f");
});
```